# Overloaded template functions deduction error

Tags: templates, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae, generic-lambda

I struggle to get this right. I want to create overloaded template functions hell that would make such calls possible and correct (GMock):

```
ASSERT_EQ(min(1, 2), 1);
ASSERT_EQ(min(std::less<>(),3,2), 2);

auto abs_comp = [](auto el1, auto el2){
  return std::abs(el1) < std::abs(el2);
};
ASSERT_EQ(min(abs_comp, -1, -5), -1);
ASSERT_EQ(min(4, 3, 2, 1), 1);
```

All is good except for this assertion:

```
ASSERT_EQ(min(std::less<>(), 3,2,1), 2);
```

And when I extract the function itself to get a meaningful error:

```
min(std::less<>(), 3,2,1)
```

I get this:

```
In file included from /home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/container_minimum_test.cpp:4:
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h: In instantiation of ‘First cppchallenge::lang::min(First, Args ...) [with First = int; Args = {}; <template-parameter-1-3> = std::enable_if<true, void>]’:
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:17:30:   required from ‘First cppchallenge::lang::min(First, Args ...) [with First = std::less<void>; Args = {int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = std::enable_if<false, void>]’
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:17:19:   required from ‘First cppchallenge::lang::min(First, Args ...) [with First = std::less<void>; Args = {int, int, int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = std::enable_if<false, void>]’
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/container_minimum_test.cpp:40:33:   required from here
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:17:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘min()’
         return min(first, min(args...));
                           ~~~^~~~~~~~~
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:8:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> T cppchallenge::lang::min(T, T)’
     T min(T first, T second) {
       ^~~
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:8:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:17:30: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         return min(first, min(args...));
                           ~~~^~~~~~~~~
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:16:11: note: candidate: ‘template<class First, class ... Args, class> First cppchallenge::lang::min(First, Args ...)’
     First min(First first, Args... args) {
           ^~~
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:16:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/rumcajs/CLionProjects/ModernCppChallenge/tst/lang/../../src/lang/container_minimum.h:17:30: note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided
         return min(first, min(args...));
                           ~~~^~~~~~~~~
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ModernCppChallengeLang.dir/build.make:102: CMakeFiles/ModernCppChallengeLang.dir/tst/lang/container_minimum_test.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: CMakeFiles/ModernCppChallengeLang.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:128: CMakeFiles/ModernCppChallengeLang.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:177: ModernCppChallengeLang] Error 2
```

The template functions are as below:

```
namespace cppchallenge::lang {
    //#1
    template<typename T>
    T min(T first, T second) {
        return first < second ? first : second;
    }

    template<typename First, typename... Args>
    using are_same = std::conjunction<std::is_same<First, Args>...>;

    //#2
    template<typename First, typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if<are_same<First, Args...>::value, void>>
    First min(First first, Args... args) {
        return min(first, min(args...));
    }

    //#3
    template<typename Comparator, typename T>
    T min(Comparator comp, T first, T second) {
        return comp(first, second) ? first : second;
    }

    //#4
    template<typename Comparator, typename First, typename... Args,
    typename = std::enable_if<are_same<First, Args...>::value, void>,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Comparator, std::function<bool(First,First)>>::value>::type>
    First min(Comparator comp, First first, Args... args) {
        return min(comp, first, min(comp, args...));
    }
}
```

The errors are pointing to function #2 though it should use #4.

Comment: Are you sure that the 4th way is usable? You pass a template lambda and try to convert it to a non templated one.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure, that's the case. I want to specify that the first param is a comparator and not the first element of the list of values to be compared. This is the solution I would think should work but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using a named template function?

Comment: What do you have in mind? Changing the name of the function? I specifically want to avoid giving up overloads.

Comment: template<typename T> bool abs_comp(T el1, T el2){
  return std::abs(el1) < std::abs(el2);} instead of a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the error is in the following template function: you have to add something as `* = nullptr` after the last `::type`

```
template<typename Comparator, typename First, typename... Args,
typename = std::enable_if<are_same<First, Args...>::value, void>,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Comparator, std::function<bool(First,First)>>::value>::type * = nullptr> // add * = nullptr
First min(Comparator comp, First first, Args... args) {
    return comp(comp, first, min(comp, args...));
}
```

or also add a `typename =` before the last `typename std::enable_if`.

Otherwise, if all goes well (if `Firts` and all `Args...` are equal and if `Comparable` is convertible to the needed `st::function`, the template signature become

```
template <typename Comparator, typename First, typename ... Args,
          typename = std::enable_if<are_same<First, Args...>::value,
          void>
```

and the last `void`, alone, doesn't make sense (and the preceding `std::enable_if` isn't much useful; but this is another problem; see the following "bonus suggestion")

You should transform in something similar to

```
template <typename Comparator, typename First, typename ... Args,
          typename = std::enable_if<are_same<First, Args...>::value, void>
          void * = nullptr>
//............^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or also

```
template <typename Comparator, typename First, typename ... Args,
          typename = std::enable_if<are_same<First, Args...>::value, void>,
          typename = void>
//........^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Bonus suggestion: the preceding SFINAE test should be

```
typename = std::enable_if_t<are_same<First, Args...>::value, void>
// ......................^^
```

or also (the last `std::enable_if_t` parameter is `void` by default)

```
typename = std::enable_if_t<are_same<First, Args...>::value>
```

otherwise the test never works and the function is ever enabled (from the point of view of the `First` and `Args...` types).

Similar problem in the SFINAE test for

```
First min(First first, Args... args)
```

Comment: What does it mean? I checked condition `std::is_convertible<Comparator, std::function<bool(First,First)>>::value` and it works. why add  `* = nullptr` ?

Comment: @AmirRasulov - yes, `std::is_convertible<Comparator, std::function<bool(First,First)>>::value` itself works; but you have to see it in the context of the template signature of the function; I've improved the answer; I hope that now if more clear.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs - check also other SFINAE tests: sometime you use `std::enable_if` when you should use `std::enable_if_t`

Comment: @max66, Thanks for explanation! If I understood problem was with forgotten `=` in `typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Comparator, std::function<bool(First,First)>>::value>::type>` ?

Comment: @max66 That's what I call a cherry pick. I wasn't aware of this helper type. Got rid of these cryptic voids. Thanks again.

Comment: @AmirRasulov - with forgotten `typename =` before of forgotten `* = nullptr` after; works in both ways; what doesn't works is an isolated `void`.